# Is it valid/relevant to do PCA on data which has multiple independent variables?

Tags: pca

I have lots of data on the effects of different drugs on ~100 cell  variables, and want to perform PCA on the data to reduce its dimensionality so the effects can be more easily visualised. The thing is I have results for different drugs at 3 different concentrations. Should I perform PCA on the effects of all drugs at one concentration, then at a different concentration, thus having only 1 independent variable for each PCA? Or alternatively should I do PCA on all the data, having identified and discarded outliers? Should I include all control data in the PCA as well?

Comment: One way to go about answering this question is to look at the difference in how PCA affects each group of variables for a different concentration. I would first apply PCA to each group separately, then examine the principal components to see how close they are. If they're relatively similar (and answering what 'relatively' means is a question of the angle between the eigenvectors) then it may be suitable to do PCA on all of them together.

Comment: This entirely depends on the goals of your analysis. Please specify those.

Comment: The goal of the analysis is to basically look for patterns in the data on how cells respond to different drug treatments

Comment: OK, and how many drugs do you have?

Comment: Also, perhaps you can specify what exactly is the control data.